# percentage sign looks italic

Tags: fonts, times

I have a problem with the percentage sign. In the font I'm using the percentage sign looks like it's in italic. I want it to look like the rest of the font.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}    
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\begin{document}

text 20~\%

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The symbol from the font [TeX Gyre Termes](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tex-gyre-termes) looks better. The TeX Gyre fonts extends the PostScript standard fonts from URW (e.g. that comes with GhostScript).

Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% the German language has umlauts
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{tgtermes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
Font & upright & italics\\
\hline
Times Roman (URW):
& \fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont text 20~\%
& \fontfamily{ptm}\itshape text 20~\%
\\
TeX Gyre Termes:
& text 20~\%
& \itshape text 20~\%
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]